# Openshift PHP application - Virtual Host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, openshift, virtualhost

I have a php application on openshift. This main application is actually made of 2 different parts: Students & Employees. As I want to keep the code clear and separate for each (even though they share some common data), I need to create Virtual Host in Openshift.

After the user logs in, depending on what his setting was - I want to direct him to either the student or the employee management section. For example say my main application is https://manage.example.com, when the user logs in I want to be able to direct him to a virtual directory(host?) such as

1. https://manage.example.com/student OR
2. https://manage.example.com/employee

I am a little new to web related development but I 'assume' that Virtual host may be the right thing? If yes then any clues or leads on how to set up Virtual hosts on Openshift as I understand I have limited access to server configuration files on Openshift.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to create more virtual hosts on OpenShift Online for one application, however, there are a couple of other routes that you can go.

1. You could create two separate applications (each having their own gears) and run each part of your code on a different application.  If you need to share a database between them, make sure that you create one of them as scaled (the one you add the database to).  Note that these two applications will not share a filesystem.
2. You could setup each application to run in it's own "subdirectory", something like you had proposed above, you should be able to easily setup the different routes in your application, this would also allow the applications to share a filesystem.